# How can I reference the validating schema in a saved JSON string?

Tags: json, json.net

I have created a number of JSON schemas that reference http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#. Let's say I call these myschema1.schema.json, myschema2.schema.json etc. I am saving JSON strings that have been validated against one of these schemas and at a later date I need to be able to edit that data and re-validate it against the original schema. How can I include a reference to the original schema in the saved JSON file? I thought about simply including it as a property but I don't want this schema property to be included when dynamically creating a class based on the JSON properties as I don't want it to be included in the edit form.

Here's what I would like to be able to do..

```
{
  "$schema": "http://someURI/myschema1",
  "Property 1": "One",
  "Property 2": "Two"
}
```

..but as the property name $schema is not included in the schema it fails validation. Any suggestions would be most welcome. Thanks!